# How to transfer data between two child component in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Actually I'm creating a front-end in which I am taking a mobile number as input on 1st page then after checking mobile number I am moving to OTP page. In OTP page I am taking otp as input and have to send both otp and mobile number to the backend. I am able to pass the otp but dont know how to pass the mobile number as I have taken it as input in the previous page.

Here is Signup Component which will take mobile number input

```
import React from 'react';
import './Signup.css';
class Signup extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            mobile:''
        }
    }

    onMobileChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({mobile: event.target.value})
    }

    onSubmitSignup = () => {
        fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://8080/signup/checkMobile',{
            method:'post',
            headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                mobile:this.state.mobile
            })
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data =>{
            if(data.content === 'OK'){
                this.props.loadNewUser(this.state.mobile);
                this.props.onRouteChange('otp','nonav');
            }
        })
        // this.props.onRouteChange('otp','nonav');
    }

    render(){
        const { onRouteChange} = this.props;
        return(
            <div className='container'>
                <div className='mt6'>
                    <img src={require('./logo.png')} className='logoimg' alt='logo'/>
                </div>
                <h3 className='text-center b' style={{font:"Montserrat"}}>FOODVIRAAM</h3>
                <div>
                <article className="br3 ba dark-gray b--white mv4 w-100 w-50-m w-25-l mw6 shadow-6 center">
                    <main className="pa4 black-80">
                        <div className="measure">
                            <fieldset id="sign_up" className="ba b--transparent ph0 mh0">
                                <div className="mt1">
                                    <label className="db fw5 lh-copy f3" htmlFor="email-address" style={{font:"Montserrat"}}>Enter your mobile number</label>
                                    <input 
                                    className="pa2 input-reset ba bg-transparent hover-bg-black bw1 br2 w-100"
                                    type="number" 
                                    name="mobile" 
                                    id="mobile"
                                    style={{borderColor:"#ffde59",lineHeight:"28px"}}
                                    onChange={this.onMobileChange}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                            <div className="tr">
                                <input 
                                onClick={this.onSubmitSignup}
                                className="pv2 input-reset ba b--white bg-transparent grow pointer f3 dib" style={{font:"Montserrat"}} type="submit" value="Send OTP"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </main>
                </article>
                </div>
                <h5 className="tc mt5" style={{font:"Montserrat"}}>{"#HighwayKaHygienicPitStop"}</h5>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Signup;
```

OTP component In which I will take OTP as input and then have to send otp and mobile number on Submit

```
import React from 'react';
import './Signup.css';
class Otp extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            otp:''
        }
    }

    onOtpChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({otp: event.target.value})
    }

    onSubmitOtp = () => {
        console.log(this.props.mobile);
        fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://8080/signup/validateOtp',{
            method:'post',
            headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                mobile:this.props.mobile,
                otp:this.state.otp
            })
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data =>{
            if(data.content === 'OK'){
                // this.props.loadNewUser(this.state.otp);
                this.props.onRouteChange('createprofile','nonav');
            }
        })
        this.props.onRouteChange('otp','nonav');
    }

    render(){
        const { mobile,onRouteChange} = this.props;
        return(
            <div className='container'>
                <div className='mt6'>
                    <img src={require('./logo.png')} className='logoimg' alt='logo'/>
                </div>
                <h3 className='text-center b' style={{font:"Montserrat"}}>FOODVIRAAM</h3>
                <div>
                <article className="br3 ba dark-gray b--white mv4 w-100 w-50-m w-25-l mw6 shadow-6 center">
                    <main className="pa4 black-80">
                        <div className="measure">
                            <fieldset id="sign_up" className="ba b--transparent ph0 mh0">
                                <div className="mt1">
                                    <label className="db fw5 lh-copy f3" htmlFor="email-address" style={{font:"Montserrat"}}>Verify OTP</label>
                                    <input 
                                    className="pa2 input-reset ba bg-transparent hover-bg-black bw1 br2 w-100"
                                    type="number" 
                                    name="mobile-number" 
                                    id="mobile-number"
                                    style={{font:"Montserrat", borderColor:"#ffde59",lineHeight:"28px"}}
                                    onChange={this.onOtpChange}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                            <div className="tr">
                                <input 
                                onClick={this.onSubmitOtp}
                                className="pv2 input-reset ba b--white bg-transparent grow pointer f3 dib" style={{font:"Montserrat"}} type="submit" value=""/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </main>
                </article>
                </div>
                <h5 className="tc mt5" style={{font:"Montserrat"}}>{"#HighwayKaHygienicPitStop"}</h5>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Otp;
```

And this is the parent class

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      route:'signup',
      route1:'nonav',
      newuser:{
        mobile:''
      }
    }
  }

  loadNewUser = (mobile)=>{
    this.setState({user: {
      mobile:mobile
    }})
    console.log(mobile); 
  }

  onRouteChange = (route, route1) =>{
    this.setState({route:route});
    this.setState({route1:route1});
  }

  render(){
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {this.state.route1==='nav'
      ? <div>
          <Navigation onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/>
          { this.state.route==='editmnc' 
            ? <EditMNC parentMethod={this.onRouteChange}>{this.props.children}</EditMNC>
            :<Revenue onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/>
          }
        </div>
       }
       : <div>
          { this.state.route==='signup'
          ? <Signup loadNewUser={this.loadNewUser} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/>
          : <div>
            { this.state.route==='otp'
             ? <Otp mobile={this.state.newuser.mobile} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/>
             : <div>
               { this.state.route==='createprofile'
               ?  <CreateProfile onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
               : <div>
                 { this.state.route==='signin'
                 ? <Signin onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
                 : <AddItem onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/>
                 }
                 </div>
               }
               </div>
            }
            </div>
        }
        </div>
      }        
    </div>
  );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should use react redux for this purpose.

Comment: @AbhilekhGautam Ok Thanks BTW I haven't used redux earlier and have to complete this assignment by today so if you can suggest any alternate method for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `localStorage` or `Cookies` to store your phone number on one page and on the next page, you can easily retrieve the data by whatever medium you choose. Since storing on either of them persist your data, you don't need to worry about an accidental refresh of the page.

Don't use `Redux` or `Context API`, as they don't persist the data.

Example :-

Using the localStorage API

```
// storing the phone number on your first page.
localStorage.setItem('$$NAMESPACE__phone_number', phoneNumber)

// getting the phone number on your second.
const phoneNumber = localStorage.getItem('$$NAMESPACE__phone_number')
```

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used localStorage earlier so if you can tell me that except these two lines if I have to add anything else then it will be really helpful

Comment: Nope. `localStorage` API is a browser API. You don't need anything. You could read about it here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Ok ... I will try this. Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you please tell me that what is  `$$NAMESPACE__phone_number` ?

Comment: You're basically storing your data as a key/value pair. $$NAMESPACE__phone_number is your key. The data is your value. It could be anything of your choice. But the same key should be used for retrieving the data. It is better if you check the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Use Redux it's a bit complicated but It is used when you need to transfer data from child to parent,
You can also get the data that you sent by props to child and got a return value

https://redux.js.org

Comment: I have to transfer data between two child component

Comment: All child elements have access to redux data, they can dispatch it and change if connected to the parent redux you can find more information in the documentations

Comment: @Altro What happens when the page accidentally get refreshed?

Comment: react-router-dom doesn't refresh the page,but yeah if the page gets refreshed that's an error :/